# HTML 'font' tags are creating white-space with genomic data

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a pretty simple HTML file that shows genomic data. However the issue with this HTML file is that it shows so much data that you have re-size your browser to over 1800px to view all the data without each line wrapping/breaking and creating a new line ( check example 1 ). I found a way to prevent this wrapping/breaking by removing all the 
 tags and wrapping each line in a div, than giving all div’s a style of ‘white-space: nowrap;’ and that seems to work ( check example 2). The real issue I’m having now is that some font tags seem to be leaving extra white space when next to another font tag. Whenever a font tag with a color blue is next to a font tag that’s colored red they create extra whitespace in-between them. When I inspect the element it shows no padding or margin associated with these font tags? So why is there a white space and how can I prevent it from happening? The whole purpose of this file is to look at alignments, so this white-space throws off the entire visualization. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

[Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lv4cdak/)

[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/csbp95wo/)
( scroll down to see phenomenon )

```
<!-- This creates white-space, why? -->

<font color=“blue”><b>T</b></font> 
<font color=“red”><b>A</b></font>
```

Comment: `<font>` is an *obsolete* element and should no longer be used, Try a `span` instead.

Comment: I understand the font tag is depreciated, but I've tried replacing them with a span, p, div, and other tags an all of them change the visualization to something completely different.

Comment: `font` isn't deprecated, it is _obsolete_: it is literally an illegal tag in HTML5, not just "not recommended". It was removed from the spec. So use `<span class="blue"><strong>T</strong></span>` and define a CSS class `.blue { color: #0B00E0; }` and use that because it looks identical but uses proper HTML.